# Setting Default Value to 'None' for Parameter (Azure Data Factory)

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am currently trying to parametrize a dataset so that the compression type of a binary file can be set without creating a new dataset.

The issue that I am having is that I cannot seem to make the compression type default to 'None' while still having a parameter. I have tried typing in null, '', etc. but nothing seems to work. The pipeline will either not run, or it returns an error that it cannot be null, invalid type "" etc. Any advice would be appreciated.

[image: Parameters in Files]

[image: I am trying to make the 'None' shown here the default value]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**--Update**

It so appears this is something to do with how Binary dataset is designed.

Going through the Binary Dataset code I can see the below difference in usage of compression method/code block.

**It indeed leads to an error for default value set to `None`.**

[image]

And when **compression type** is set to `None`

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

**You can** reach out to support for official response or log an issue [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/new) or share an idea [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/1219ec2d-6c26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c?page=1&sort=most-votes#)

---

Also, it works fine when **using the Default `None` option from the dropdown** for compression properties in case of Binary dataset.

Checkout..

[image]

---

### However...

I have tried this at both source and sink with csv files - `Source.csv` and `Source.csv.gz` both ways

You can set the parameter default value to `None`. And it works just fine.

[image]

Same is expected for Binary format [Dataset properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-binary#dataset-properties) but in vain

Comment: Odd... I have the default value set to none just as you have shown, but I still get this error: 


ErrorCode=UserErrorInvalidPluginType,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.PluginNotRegisteredException,Message=Invalid type 'None' is provided in 'compression'. Please correct the type in payload and retry.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'

Comment: Please check the updated, you are correct. You can try reaching out to support or log an issue

Comment: Thank you for confirming Karthik, I will try reach out to Microsoft support.

Comment: It's my pleasure 

Answer (score 0):

Not an obvious solution, but you can add a parameter named "CompressionType" to your dataset and then edit the dataset json to add this under "typeProperties":

```
"@if(equals(dataset().CompressionType,'None'),'no_compression','compression')": {
    "type": "@dataset().CompressionType"
}
```